# Cholsky and Group Structure of Correlation matrices

Tags: matrices, group-theory, correlation, positive-definite, positive-semidefinite

If $X$ and $Y$ are correlation matrices which are strictly positive definite and $A$, and $B$ are their respective Cholsky decompositions.  Then is
$$
(AB)(AB)^{\star},
$$
again a strictly positive-definite correlation matrix?